# How to properly accept input from another terminal (say, pts/1)?

Tags: c, linux, unix, linux-device-driver

I tried printing into another terminal by simply using

```
fd=open("/dev/pts/0",O_RDWR);
write(fd,"hello",5);
```

and it worked properly. However I tried to read a series of characters in the same way and it appeared that the order of input was inconsistent.

```
fd=open("/dev/pts/0",O_RDWR);
read(fd,&ch1,1);
read(fd,&ch2,1);
read(fd,&ch3,1);
```

and I entered data "abcde" in pts/0, but when I printed the output I got "acd" and sometimes I would get "bce". Can someone explain this behavior? I read somewhere that Unix does not allow input from other terminals but even so how are these characters being received by the program running in pts/1?

Comment: That's because pts is a _pseudo-terminal slave_ - a two way channel connected to "pseudo-terminal master" (`/dev/ptmx` on most systems). So probably /dev/pts/0 is already in use and somebody tries to read from it, try `lsof | grep /dev/pts/0` (Linux-specific) to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If two processes are both reading from the same terminal, each bit of input data will go to only one of the two processes.  So you are seeing a subset of the data, and the shell or other program that you are running on the terminal is getting the remaining data.

Output is also a combination of the output created by both processes, but that corresponds to what you want intuitively.  (I.e., your shell probably didn't output anything during the experiment, and you output "hello", the combination of nothing and "hello" is "hello".)